# Capture Keyboard press event in the MainActivity from any Fragment in Android

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-textwatcher, android-touch-event

Due to a security constraint in my app, the users are logged out if there is inactivity for >2mins.

In my MainActivity I have Overided **dispatchTouchEvent** and it is called every time the user interacts with the app.

But **dispatchKeyEvent** is not called if users are typing something into the app. So the app kicks the user out if they are typing for more than 2 mins.

How should I capture any Key Press Event in my app in without adding a TextWathcer?

Comment: u can detect if keyboard is open and pause the timer of inactivity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dispatchKeyEvent` takes in a **KeyEvent** object as parameter. And
[From Android documentation:](https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/commands)

> Note: When handling keyboard events with the KeyEvent class and
>   related APIs, you should expect that such keyboard events come only
>   from a **hardware keyboard**. You should never rely on receiving key
>   events for any key on a soft input method (an on-screen keyboard).

Also [from here:](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent)

> As soft input methods can use multiple and inventive ways of inputting
>   text, there is no guarantee that any key press on a soft keyboard will
>   generate a key event: this is left to the IME's discretion, and in
>   fact sending such events is discouraged. You should never rely on
>   receiving KeyEvents for any key on a soft input method. In particular,
>   the default software keyboard will never send any key event to any
>   application targetting Jelly Bean or later, and will only send events
>   for some presses of the delete and return keys to applications
>   targetting Ice Cream Sandwich or earlier.

In order to dispatch key events from an on-screen keyboard you, have to add textWatcher to your editText.

**For example:**

```
myEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

                }
            });
```